# How to find the date of an Ethereum transaction while parsing it with web3?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

**Is there a way to know the date of a transaction by looking at the raw blockchain data?**

I know that Etherscan and other blockchain explorers have dates for the transactions, but I couldn't find a way to do it via web3.

[web3.eth.getTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransaction), and other transaction related [APIs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API)
don't seem to be exposing any Date objects.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`web3.eth.getTransaction({txhash})` will contain a blockNumber.

Use [web3.eth.getBlock](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetblock) to retrieve the block details and you will find the following field:

```
 timestamp: Number - the unix timestamp for when the block was collated.
```

This is a Unix timestamp.

Example using `geth` for the following transaction [0x5da2844afb6826d4baed6ad7e8b536c00cbc921ac147773ad056f29f2e7c1762](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5da2844afb6826d4baed6ad7e8b536c00cbc921ac147773ad056f29f2e7c1762).

```
> let tx = "0x5da2844afb6826d4baed6ad7e8b536c00cbc921ac147773ad056f29f2e7c1762"
> web3.eth.getTransaction(tx).blockNumber
1920050
> web3.eth.getBlock(1920050).timestamp
1469021581
```

And using [www.unixtimestamp.com](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php), this works out to be `07/20/2016 @ 1:33pm (UTC)` which matches the etherscan.io details.

Comment: also you can convert it directly with javascript   

`var dateTimeStamp = web3.eth.getBlock(1920050).timestamp //outputs 1469021581`      
`var d = new Date(dateTimeStamp * 1000) //x1000 to convert from seconds to milliseconds`    
`var s = d.toUTCString()`    
`s = s.substring(0,s.indexOf("GMT")) + "UTC" //change the confusing 'GMT' to 'UTC'`  
`s`    

outputs   "Wed, 20 Jul 2016 13:33:01 UTC"

Comment: Just to add, to switch between timestamps and human-readable timestamps in https://www.epochconverter.com/#code there are a lot of routines for differebt languages

Comment: This doesn't work with `web3` v1.0

Comment: `web3.eth.getTransaction(tx)` returns a `Promise` so `web3.eth.getTransaction(tx).blockNumber` is not correct. It should be `let { blockNumber } = await web3.eth.getTransaction(tx)` instead.

Answer (score 9):

To get the exact date and time, include the following code:

```
> var date = web3.eth.getBlock(1920050).timestamp 
1469021581
> var date1 = new Date(date*1000);
 undefined
>console.log(date1.toUTCString())
 Tue, 06 Dec 2016 09:32:13 UTC
```

Answer (score 3):

While most of the answers are providing information on how to obtain the block time (and they are correct), note that the transaction only takes place once it is added in a block and that block is successfully mined. Prior to that it would still be pending i.e. it still hasn't taken place.

In fact, if you look at transactions within a block on Etherscan, they all have the same timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

This is the timestamp of a block (when it was collated) not specifically of a transaction. I guess we are still awaiting the answer.

Comment: The time of the block and the transaction are the same, since all the transactions in the block are committed at the same moment as the block

Answer (score 0):

Actually none of these answers are correct.

Valid and working answer is:

```
web3.eth.getBlock(BLOCK_NUMBER_HERE, (error, block) => {
    const timestamp = block.timestamp;

    // here you go
});
```

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? :D

Comment: Upvoted purely because the downvoter never provided an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Hello I tried this and its working :

```
web3.eth.getBlock(BLOCKNUMBER, (err, block) => {
            console.log(err,block);
            this.setState({block});
        });

this.setState({timestamp: this.state.block.timestamp});
```